# RadListView automatically sorting on ID column

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, telerik

I am using the Telerik radlistview o display some results, i perform some grouping in my query and return a sorted and ordered resultset and set it to the datasource. For some reason (which i have been battling with all morning) the ListView re-orders the results by the ID column.

```
<telerik:RadListView runat="server" ID="rlThumbnailView" OnNeedDataSource="rlThumbnailView_NeedDataSource"
                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" OnDataBound="rlThumbnailView_DataBound" OnItemDataBound="rlThumbnailView_ItemDataBound">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <span style="vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: 4px">Displaying page
                        <%#Container.CurrentPageIndex + 1 %>
                        of
                        <%#Container.PageCount %></span> </span>
                    <br />
                    <div id="list">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Style="float: left; margin-left: 160px" Visible="<%#Container.PageCount > 1 %>">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="PrevButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev"
                                Text="Prev Page" Enabled="<%#Container.CurrentPageIndex > 0 %>" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="NextButton" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next"
                                Text="Next Page" Enabled="<%#Container.CurrentPageIndex < Container.PageCount - 1 %>" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <div>
                            <telerik:RadSlider runat="server" ID="RadSlider1" MaximumValue="3" MinimumValue="1"
                                Value="2" LiveDrag="false" SmallChange="1" AutoPostBack="true" OnValueChanged="RadSlider1_ValueChanged"
                                Width="150px" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;">
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <div style="clear: both;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="wrapper" runat="server" style="float: left; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px;">

                                <telerik:RadBinaryImage ID="ThumnailImage1" runat="server" />

                            UPC:
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUPC" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                            Description:
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <div id="dvCountries" runat="server">
                                Languages:</div>
                            Changes:<asp:Label ID="lblChanges" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            Pack Format:<asp:Label ID="lblPackType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            Date Completed:<asp:Label ID="lblDateCompleted" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListView>
```

I beleive this is based on the standard microsoft listview,

Comment: If i remove "AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" the results dont get resorted

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who faces the same issue, the answer appears here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/listview/listview-paging-and-sortorder.aspx

seems to be a bug with Telerik